# Does changing order in NetBeans set tab order?

Tags: java, netbeans, tab-ordering

I changed the order of components on my JFrame in NetBeans. Does that set the tab order? Some of the orders do not seem to be working correctly.

Comment: If you mean the order in which components are visited when the user navigates between them, the answer is yes and no. Typically the order is defined in part with the layout manager, which may not always layout components in the order they were added to the container

Comment: @MadProgrammer Do you know how I would go about setting it? I don't want to start messing with stuff then mess something up.

Comment: [How to use the Focus Subsystem](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html)